# Why does foundation some times not size the columns equally?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have this foundation JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nycynik/qn8z3cut/2/

and it does not look like tic-tac-toe, instead the right column is flush right, and the rest are all different sizes.  I expected them to all have the same size.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns yellow_gradient">
                <h2>1C</h2>
                <p>Rough Diamond</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Poor Performance<br/>High Potential</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns green_gradient">
                <h2>1B</h2>
                <p>Future Star</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Good Performance<br/>High Potential</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns green_gradient">
                <h2>1A</h2>
                <p>Consistent Star</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Outstanding Performance<br/>High Potential</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns yellow_gradient">
                <h2>2C</h2>
                <p>Inconsistent Player</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Poor Performance<br/>Moderate Potential (new role)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns yellow_gradient">
                <h2>2B</h2>
                <p>Key Player</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Good Performance<br/>Moderate Potential</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns green_gradient">
                <h2>2A</h2>
                <p>Current Star</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Outstanding Performance<br/>Moderate Potential</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns red_gradient">
                <h2>3C</h2>
                <p>Talent Risk</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Poor Performance<br/>Limited Potential</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns yellow_gradient">
                <h2>3B</h2>
                <p>Solid Professional</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Good Performance<br/>Moderate Potential</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns yellow_gradient">
                <h2>3A</h2>
                <p>High Professional</p>
                <hr />
                <p>Outstanding Performance<br/>Limited Potential</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foundation.min.css` stylesheet you're linking to does not include any of the column classes, e.g. `small-12` or `medium-4`.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn8z3cut/4/) linking to Foundations current CDN stylesheet at http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css

Comment: I did not realize that the box model was an optional item.

Comment: @nycynik Foundations SASS base is completely modular; I always just include whatever I need. No idea why the compiled CSS you linked to excludes the base grid classes, though.